# Xamarin Forms .NET Standard Project can't add Web Reference

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, .net-standard, web-reference

I'm creating Xamarin Forms App with following projects:

.Net Standard 2.0

Android

iOS

UWP

On the platform-specific projects it is possible to add Web Reference, but on the first one there is only "Reference". How do I add WebReference to the .NET Standard Project?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47412894/how-to-add-service-reference-in-net-standard-project