# Add WCF Service Reference not visible in Connected Services

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2019, service-reference

I have a SDK style project in latest version of Visual Studio 2019 (with Windows Communication Foundation component installed). But I don't have the possibility to add a WCF reference to my project, it's just not visible.

I need the following item in red circle:

[image]

Has anyone any idea, why I don't have this item in my Visual Studio?

More info: I'm working with .NET Framework 4.8

As you can see, it's not visible on my machine:
[image]
[image]

To make it more clear: It's not possible to choose `WCF Web Service Reference Provider` in `Connected Services`:

[image]

Comment: I have this issue - did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

You try to directly right-click the project to add, see if this post can help you find a solution
[How to "Add Service Reference" in .NET Standard project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47412894/how-to-add-service-reference-in-net-standard-project)
[image]
[image]

Comment: You probably don't have `Sdk style` projects. With those, the window you are talking about doesn't show up. The screenshots I have will show up then.

Comment: I revised the answer, hope it helps you.

Comment: As soon as I clicked `MyProject > Right Click > Add > Service reference` and closed the dialog box, I was able to see `Connected Services > Add Service Reference` 

Answer (score 2):

You need this in your project file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services\" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

It enables the `Connected Services > Add Service Reference`